# getting message "psql is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Tags: windows, environment-variables, psql

I am trying to run commands using psql but getting the above error message.  Others suggested adding the path to the system environment variables but i did this and it still doesn't work.

I added the following to the environment variables :  C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\10.8\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\10.8\lib
but this didn't fix it.

Comment: Can you show the output of `path`? Do you call `psql` from a program? If yes, are the environment variables set there too? Could it be a permission problem?

Comment: I called psql from the command prompt.   To edit the environment variables I just went to system properties.

Comment: Ok, and what is the output of `path` from `cmd.exe`?